# How we can use same Tags into two AWS::DynamoDB::Table with in Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create Amazon DynamoDB tables using Cloud Formation Template. So my question is can I Used same Tags in multiple Tables using Ref.

```
 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
      "Resources": {
        "Status": {
          "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
          "Properties": {
            "AttributeDefinitions": [
              {
                "AttributeName": "SId",
                "AttributeType": "S"
              }
            ],
            "KeySchema": [
              {
                "AttributeName": "SId",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
              }
            ],
            "ProvisionedThroughput": {
              "ReadCapacityUnits": "1",
              "WriteCapacityUnits": "1"
            },
            "TableName": "Statuscf",
           
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Application",
                "Value": "BFMS"
              },
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "EventSourcingDataStore"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "BMSHSData": {
          "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
          "Properties": {
           
            
            "TableName": "Billing.FmsDatacf",
           
            "Tags": [{"Ref":"/Status/Tags"}]
          }
        }
      }
```

Please suggest me how I can used same tags in another table. I am using  Like this "Tags": [{"Ref":"/Status/Tags"}].

Comment: Sorry, question is not clear. What's wrong with your current template? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to used same Tags in multiple tables of cloudformation Template.


 example:- "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Application",
                "Value": "BFMS"
              },
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "EventSourcingDataStore"
              }
            ]


want to used this Tags in multiple table for same Resources.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this using plain CloudFormation is by copy-and-paste. So you have to replicate your tags for all tables "manually". The only automated solution would be through development of [CloduFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). Yet another choice could be through the use of [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html).

Comment: I don't want to add multiple Stacks. How we can add tags with in all table from same stacks. I am writing same tags for multiple tables. Want to store all tags in variable or used ref of variable in table.

Comment: @user3287006 I already wrote, you have to create macro or custom resource.

Comment: Could you please provide me some sample code of macro or custom resource?  Thanks

Comment: @user3287006 I linked AWS documentation with the examples, so please study that.

Comment: I tried with both of articles but still facing same issue. Could you guide me how its working ?
And how we can add tags in Custome resource and pass in DynamoDb Table. COuld you please post a sample code for me if possible

Comment: @user3287006 Can you please show your custom resources or macros that you created and explain why they dont work.

Comment: Thanks for respond. I have resolved that issue through Custom resource. There was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To resolved this problem, Just need to pass Tags Properties in the Parameter Section of CF.
[image]

Then used those tags in DynamoDB like this

[image]